# 1004 paste method of worksheet class failed in excel 2007 vba

Tags: vba, excel

Following code works well in Excel 2016 but when same run on Excel 2007

> 1004 paste method of worksheet class failed

Error encountered.

```
Sub productPicture()
    Sheet1.Select

    lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C4").Value Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Copy
        End If

        Exit For
    Next i

    Sheet2.Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9:G17").Clear
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9:G17").Select
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: NOTE: Be aware that `Sheet1` is not the same as `Sheets(1)`. The first is a sheet name second is the position of a sheet in the tab bar. So a sheet named `Sheet1` can be any position in the tab bar e.g. `Sheets(5)`. Also avoid `.Select`: See [VBA Best Practices - Avoid using Select or Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate). Also reading [Never assume the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) might be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your code could look like following a best practices. See the comments in the code for details on each.

```
Option Explicit 'Using this as very first line will ensure all variables are declared.

Public Sub ProductPicture()
    Dim iRow As Long            'row iteration
    Dim lRow As Long            'last used row

    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet      'source worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet     'destination worksheet

    Set wsSrc = Sheet1          'set source worksheet
    Set wsDest = Sheet2         'set destination worksheet


    lRow = wsSrc.Cells(wsSrc.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row   'find last used row

    For iRow = 2 To lRow
        If wsSrc.Cells(iRow, 1) = wsDest.Range("C4").Value Then
            With wsDest.Range("D9:G17")
                .Clear  'If you clear, then always clear BEFORE copy
                        'because `clear` kills the for copy selected range
                        'like `Application.CutCopyMode = False`

                wsSrc.Cells(iRow, 2).Copy    'copy from source

                .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll     'paste into destination range: see `With …`
            End With

            'Exit For
            'probably this is the position you might want the Exit For
            'instead of below
        End If

        Exit For 'exit for at this position doesn't make sense at all,
                 'because it will ALWAYS exit here without iterating iRow
                 'you don't need a loop then if this was your aim.
    Next iRow
End Sub
```

***Note:*** *You might have a look at [Shai Rado's answer][1] too, which is a different and probably preferable approach.*

Comment: nice, but still I think using `Match` can shorten and simplify the code by a lot

Comment: @ShaiRado I agree with you about the approach with `Match`. But I wanted to show how the original approach of the OP could look like, so he can comprehend which parts were wrong and learn how it could be fixed. Added a note.

Comment: agree, that's why +1 :) It might be also easier to use `For` before switching to `Match`

Comment: This is working for text but i have picture to copy which is not copied using your method. Can you help me out with that

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `For` loop to scan all the values in column "A", you can use the `Match` function, it will save you precious time, and once you get to learin how to use it, it's one of the best tools in VBA.

Also, the better order of actions, is first `Clear` the `Range` where you intend to Paste later, and then you can use `Copy` >> `Paste` in a 1-line syntax, such as :

```
.Range("B" & MatchRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9")
```

**Note**: I usually use the `With` statement, it makes the code look nicer and shorter, also all `Range` and `Cells` objects are then fully qualified with the `Worksheet` Object. (instead of using `Select`, which is not recommended).

***Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub productPicture()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim MatchRow As Long

    ' first clear the Range where you want to paste
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9:G17").Clear

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        ' === instead of Loop use Match function ==
        ' make sure Match was able to find a amatch in the range
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C4").Value, .Range("A2:A" & LastRow), 0)) Then
            MatchRow = Application.Match(ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C4").Value, .Range("A2:A" & LastRow), 0)

            ' Copy >> Paste in a 1-line command
            .Range("B" & MatchRow).Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9")
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of image being pasted in specified range there is text as "Image" can you help me with that

Comment: @KalpeshRawal  not sure I understand what you mean, can you share your Worksheet? So i can see

Comment: @ ShaiRado Where should I share. Can you give me email id or something.

Comment: @KalpeshRawal you need to edit your post, and an image there of your worksheet

Comment: failed to upload there. They allow only images you can download from dropbox. https://www.dropbox.com/s/nwsvw5g47c4vupb/Order%20Deatils%20New.xlsm?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub productPicture()
Sheet1.Select

Lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 2 To Lastrow
    If Cells(i, 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("C4").Value Then
            Sheet2.Select
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9:G17").Clear
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("D9:G17").Select

            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Copy
            Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    End If

    Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I recommend reading [VBA Best Practices - Avoid using Select or Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9292/avoid-using-select-or-activate). Using `.Select` or `Selection.` is very bad practice. Also posting code without explanation is bad practice: See [answer].

Comment: This is working for text but i have picture to copy which is not copied using your method. Can you help me out with that.